# Does gulp.src().pipe().dest() complete before the next line? Can I call gulp.src().pipe().dest() multiple times?

Tags: promise, gulp

I'm supporting a build process that uses gulp and trying to troubleshoot a problem.  To troubleshoot this, I'd like to know if the code that makes multiple calls to gulp.src().pipe().dest() in a single gulp task is legal and correctly written.

More exactly, I want to know if gulp.src().pipe().dest() completes prior to the next javascript line that makes another call to gulp.src().pipe().dest().

The code would look like this:

```
gulp.src(getSrcFiles())
    .pipe(dostuff)
    .pipe(dostuff2)
    .dest('temp');
// will the above copy complete before I try doing substitutions 
gulp.src('temp/**')
    .pipe(mySubstitutions)
    .dest('temp')
gulp.src('temp/**')
    .dest('dist')
```

The question is will the first pipeline of `gulp.src().pipe().pipe().dest()` complete prior to the next line which performs some variable substitutions on the files copied in the first pipeline?

I didn't see the answer in the gulp documentation at https://gulpjs.org/API.html#gulp-dest-path-options.

Some other questions I found that did not answer my question were:

- [One Promise for Multiple Promises - Concurrency Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081983/one-promise-for-multiple-promises-concurrency-issue)
- [Q.js Promises in Gulp Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913094/q-js-promises-in-gulp-loop) (not answered, but similar issue being raised).
- [Using Gulp 4 with Promises to Clean/Copy Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181234/using-gulp-4-with-promises-to-clean-copy-files)
- [gulp run sequence after promise resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514826/gulp-run-sequence-after-promise-resolve) (similar question not answered)
- [How does gulp treat the Promise of a then()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404088/how-does-gulp-treat-the-promise-of-a-then) (similar question, crickets, no answer:-))

More questions but no answers...  I have a gut feeling I'm going to answer this one myself after I figure it out, and then I'll be able to answer some of the other questions.

A great question and answer that will help me understand gulp and how it ensures ordering of tasks is [What does Gulp "done" method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694425/what-does-gulp-done-method-do).
The gulp npm run-sequence docs were also very useful, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence.

UPDATE: I found someone else who reported this as a problem.

- See https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1254

Comment: For a start, I wouldn't consider the answer in `Gulp Stream completion with promises` as anything useful!

Comment: the returned value of those gulp chains is a stream, if I read the code correctly (`gulp` requires `vinyl-fs` requires `lead` and that's where some stream majicks is happening). Given this, I suspect `gulp...etc` would be asynchronous. You may be able do something like https://pastebin.com/scjJtvtZ

Comment: @Bravo, I'll remove that reference as it was just confusing to me. :-)  I appreciate your pastebin code.  I see now that the vinyl approach is likely on solid footing based on how gulp.src(), and pipe work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the answer I was looking for:

- **Will gulp.src().pipe().dest() completes prior to the next javascript line that makes another call to gulp.src().pipe().dest().**  No.  A stream pipeline is started but not necessarily completed when the next javascript line is run.
- **Can you use multiple `gulp.src().pipe().dest()` in a single gulp task?**  Yes, but you must write the gulp task in a special way to handle this (shown below).

The following code shows how to write a gulp task that makes several gulp.src().dest() copies.  The way it works is to convert the gulp.src().pipe() stream into a promise, and then use Promise.all() to wait for all of the streams to complete before saying that the gulp task is complete.

```
gulp.task('task', function (doneWithTaskCb) {
  return Promise.all([
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      gulp.src(src + '/*.md')
        .pipe(plugin())
        .on('error', reject)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
        .on('end', resolve)
    }),
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      gulp.src(src + '/*.md')
        .pipe(plugin())
        .on('error', reject)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
        .on('end', resolve)
    })
  ]).then(function () {
    doneWithTaskCb();
  });
});
```

I didn't come up with it.  The credit goes to TySound at https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1181#issuecomment-126694791.

The important code is this pattern:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject)  {
    gulp.src()
      .pipe()
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
      .end('end', resolve);
}
```

That code creates a promise that when it resolves the pipeline is finished.  So in essence, it converts the "stream" into a promise.

The code that calls `doneWithTaskCb()` is important because that is how gulp knows that the current task is complete.

```
Promise.all( [ new Promise(), new Promise() ] )
    .then(function() { 
        doneWithTaskCb(); 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks - your answer made me revamp my whole gulpfile.js code but finally it solved me all the issues.